# Failed to read attributes from XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dictionary

I've tried a lot of attempts and did a lot of reading and research. This final code finally read my XML file and did get the correct number of lines in my XML file. However, what I got inside the dictionary typed variable are Null values

this is my code:

```
public void ParkingStatus()
{
    _Default defaultPage = new _Default();

    //baca dari XML file
    XDocument xmlDocReader = XDocument.Load(@".\carpark.xml");

    var tempDict = xmlDocReader.Root.Elements("Lot")
        .ToDictionary(c => c.Elements("name"), c => c.Elements("timeOut"));

    foreach (var iterate in tempDict)
    {
        bool statusParking;
        if (iterate.Value.ToString() == "")
            statusParking = true;
        else
            statusParking = false;

        defaultPage.ParkingStatus.Add(iterate.Key.ToString(), statusParking);
    }
}
```

my XML file is as below: (carpark.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Lot>
     <Lot name="W101" timeIn="2014-11-23 13:22" timeOut="" />
     <Lot name="W102" timeIn="" timeOut="2014-11-23 13:35" />
     <Lot name="W103" timeIn="" timeOut="2014-11-23 11:35" />
     <Lot name="W104" timeIn="2014-11-23 13:35" timeOut="" />
     <Lot name="W105" timeIn="2014-11-23 08:00" timeOut="" />
     <Lot name="W106" timeIn="2014-11-23 07:56" timeOut="" />
     <Lot name="W107" timeIn="" timeOut="2014-11-23 13:15" />
     <Lot name="W108" timeIn="2014-11-23 07:35" timeOut="" />
     <Lot name="W109" timeIn="" timeOut="2014-11-23 12:55" />
     <Lot name="W110" timeIn="2014-11-23 09:00" timeOut="" />
     <Lot name="W111" timeIn="" timeOut="2014-11-23 12:45" />
     <Lot name="W112" timeIn="" timeOut="2014-11-23 13:01" />
</Lot>
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Lot` is an element but `name`, `timeIn` and `timeout` are attributes.

```
<Lot name="W102" timeIn="" timeOut="2014-11-23 13:35" />
```

For that reason you should use the [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute(v=vs.110).aspx) method on the Element.

```
 var tempDict = xmlDocReader.Root.Elements("Lot")
        .ToDictionary(c => c.Attributes("name").FirstOrDefault(), 
                      c => c.Attributes("timeOut").FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Encountered another problem with this line 
      
    `defaultPage.ParkingStatus.Add(iterate.Key.ToString(), statusParking);`

when debugging the key value added to the dictionary is this "System.Xml.Linq.XElement+<GetAttributes>d_0"

whereby it is supposed to be "W101", "W102" and so on. In the tempDict the key values are correct. hence I am getting the same duplicate key inserted error.

Answer (score 2):

No need for a temporary dictionary:

```
foreach (var el in xmlDocReader.Root.Elements("Lot"))
{
    string name = (string)el.Attribute("name");
    string timeOut = (string)el.Attribute("timeOut");

    ...
}
```